# webpack dev server throws 404

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I cannot webpack dev server to work with my current configurations. I keep getting 404 without any errors or hints as to why or what is causing the error.
My project source directory structure

```
.src
├── client
│   ├── client.ts
│   ├── index.html
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── server
    ├── server.ts
    └── tsconfig.json
```

My webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const copyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/client/client.ts",
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    watchFiles: ["src/**/*"],
    //port: 3000,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    open: "Chrome",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new copyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "./src/client/index.html", to: "/client/index.html" }],
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    publicPath: "/",
    clean: true,
  },
};
```

I am using `"start": "webpack serve --mode=development --open",` as my start script.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

adding  `static: path.join(__dirname, "./src/client"),` under the webpack `devServer` object in the configuration resolved my issue.
The full config in case it helps someone else

```
const path = require("path");
const copyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/client/client.ts",
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    watchFiles: ["src/**/*"],
    port: 3000,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    open: "Chrome",
    static: path.join(__dirname, "./src/client"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new copyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "src/client/index.html", to: "/client/index.html" }],
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    publicPath: "/",
    clean: true,
  },
};
```